# error: void value not ignored as it ought to be in C program

Tags: c

When I try to compile my program which has two functions I keep getting this error:

```
    exer1.c: In function ‘main’:
    exer1.c:15:14: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void addition_1(int *num1, int *num2);
int main(void) {

        int num1;
        int num2;
        int finalAnswer;

        printf("number one: ");
        scanf("%d", &num1);

        printf("number two: ");
        scanf("%d", &num2);

        finalAnswer = addition_1(&num1, &num2);

        return 0;

}

void addition_1(int *num1, int *num2) {

        int total;

        total = *num1 + *num2;
        print("%d + %d = %d", *num1, *num2,total);
}
```

I know I don't need to use the pointers, but I want to use pointers for a learning experience and to understand. Is there a away to skip the result when I compile the program?

Comment: This rubbish was asked only yesterday!!  It's almost identical code.  Homework, or what??

Comment: You in the same class a @Joe Woods?

Answer (score 0):

It says it all. `addition_1` is returning `void` (i.e. returning nothing). But this line:

```
finalAnswer = addition_1(&num1, &num2);
```

is assigning the (not) returned value to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You attempt to assign the return value of the function `addition_1` to `finalAnswer`, even though the function doesn't return anything at all. You can eliminate this error in two ways:

1. Remove the assignment to `finalAnswer` (and its definition). You don't use the variable at all.
2. Change the function's declaration/definition to

   ```
   int addition_1(int *num1, int *num2)
   ```

   and return `total` if you want to work on the sum later.